# SQL Way To Duplicate Rows Based on a Column Value

Tags: t-sql

[image]

I need to basically duplicate each row with every other dept value, so looking at the first row where the dept is Other, I need a second row duplicated with the dept name being Math.  There could be multiple depts, so I need a new row for each potential dept.  Is there a way to do this through SQL?

```
Select  743818 teacherPersonID, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS' teacherDisplay, 'FT' personnelStatus, 1.0 ftePosition, 'Other' dept, 'INTRO TO COMPUTER SCIENCE, STUDENT ASST' course_name, 28 ttlStudents, 4 termSeq, 'course1' courseName, 'students1' courseStudents
Into    #teacherCourses
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Math', 'ALGEBRA 3, MATH 115 KSU COLLEGE ALGEBRA', 30, 4, 'course2', 'students2'
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Math', 'STUDENT ASST, ADVANCED GEOMETRY', 24, 4, 'course3', 'students3'
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Other', 'STUDENT ASST, ADVANCED GEOMETRY', 24, 4, 'course3', 'students3'
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Math', 'ADVANCED GEOMETRY', 25, 4, 'course4', 'students4'
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Math', 'MATH 115 KSU COLLEGE ALGEBRA, ALGEBRA 3', 21, 4, 'course6', 'students6'
UNION 
Select  743818, 'STUTZ, DOUGLAS', 'FT', 1.0, 'Math', 'ALGEBRA 3, MATH 115 KSU COLLEGE ALGEBRA', 19, 4, 'course7', 'students7'
```

Comment: Do you have a table with all the departments in? if so, just `CROSS JOIN` to that.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you @Larnu!!